# selecting two colums among many columns

Tags: python, split, with-statement

I have a data set which looks like this (file name:custom):

```
1 1 65.39 0.372404 -0.788955 -2.8455 -1.09717
2 1 65.39 0.367242 1.60121 -0.460432 -1.53554
10 2 16 -0.352459 -1.66367 -1.20991 -0.382338
12 2 16 -0.386501 1.15155 -2.3643 -0.924258
6 1 65.39 0.368096 -1.6016 0.453956 -1.53428
15 2 16 -0.387579 -1.15008 2.35207 -0.919574
5 1 65.39 0.374176 0.792712 2.83707 -1.08298
9 2 16 -0.354946 1.70919 1.21546 -0.390097
3 1 65.39 0.363083 -1.30479 -0.834649 1.57459
11 2 16 -0.375158 -0.403614 -2.52878 0.871748
4 1 65.39 0.370609 1.60183 -2.52762 1.05139
16 2 16 -0.357762 2.05067 -0.683076 0.438964
7 1 65.39 0.371291 -1.61835 2.52926 1.04944
13 2 16 -0.357278 -2.06082 0.680406 0.438092
8 1 65.39 0.365109 1.29671 0.840627 1.5585
14 2 16 -0.380327 0.38719 2.546 0.884682
```

I would like to select 2nd and 4th column then, order in 2nd column like:

```
1 0.372404
1 0.367242
...
2 -0.352459
2 -0.386501
...
```

To do that so I have tried

```
with open(custom,"r") as f:
    noa = f.readline()
    noa = int(noa)            <------- ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10
    config = [ [ 0 for i in range(4) ] for j in range(self.noa) ]
        for i in range(noa):
            dummy  = f.readline()
            spliter = dummy.split()
            config[i][1] = float(spliter[1])
            config[i][3] = float(spliter[3])
```

I have tried with len(noa) but it's not working.

Also, how to 'sorted' in column like in above form?

Comment: Just use the pandas library, it will make things much simpler!

Answer (score 2):

I would read your data into a dataframe, and process it in pandas. Like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(custom, delimiter='')
```

You can then access columns like this:

```
col_1 = df.iloc[0]
```

Where 0 represents the first column, 1 the 2nd column, etc.

Comment: which gives this format "1             10.000000
1.1            2.000000
65.39         16.000000
0.372404      -0.352459
-0.788955     -1.663670
-2.8455       -1.209910
-1.09717      -0.382338
Unnamed: 7          NaN
Name: 0, dtype: float64"